# Syntax for 301 redirect of www to non-www using httpd.conf

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

How do I setup a rule (on httpd.conf) to redirect all the traffic from `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`? Will the following work?

```
<VirtualHost www.domain.com>
      Redirect 301 / http://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

*Where* should I put this tag in `httpd.conf`? Does the order matter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an example of what you can use/do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain.com"
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com

  <Directory "/path/to/public_html">
      allow from all
      Options +Indexes
  </Directory>

  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

The Redirect 301 is good to use but does not have the same flexibility as a rewrite rule.

Comment: I think that you posted exactly the opposite of what I want to achieve: I want all www.domain.com to go to domain.com - not vice versa, but thanks! it definitely helped!

Comment: sorry yes, (I used my virtual host config) - I updated the rule.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer the min the system will let me (I have to wait 1 min - not sure why)