# htaccess 301 redirect root only

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site in a folder called patients

urls look like this:

http://site.com/patients/post-name

I want to redirect

site.com/patients/post-name → newsite.com/post-name

AND

site.com/patients/ → newsite.com/

I've tried this, but site.com/patients still directs to newsitesite.com/patients

```
Redirect 301 ^/patients/$ http://www.newsite.com/
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

Does htaccess have some ssort of regex to match just the root of **/patients/** and then another one for **/patients/whatever-comes-next** ?

Answer (score 1):

```
REDIRECT 301 /patients http://newsite.com
```

does that work?

Comment: I have thousands of posts, I can't write a line for every post, need a catch all solution.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are two solutions for "301" POST error:

1) Always add a trailing backslash to your "POST" URL (preferred)

2) Create an "Alias" in your httpd.conf file for the "POST" URL:

In your case, you want a redirect for *two* purposes.  Check out this link (closed as off-topic, but still useful):

- [Syntax for 301 redirect of www to non-www using httpd.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322454/syntax-for-301-redirect-of-www-to-non-www-using-httpd-conf)

Comment: 1) I can't tell visitors to always add a slash

Comment: 2) I don't have access to httpd.conf. Looking to do this with htaccess

Comment: Is there not some sort of regex for the exact match of /patients/ and then the match of /patients/**** ?