# Adding WWW to the URL using httpd.conf configuration

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I was adviced recently that the best practice to add `WWW` to an URL is by configuring the `httpd.conf` file and *not* the `.htaccess` rule.

I have been googling but havent found the configuration yet. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this in httpd.conf file . here is a full description [httpd.con rewrite rules updated link](http://geekflare.com/redirect-non-www-to-www-non-www/). please read the documentation from the link provided.

```
    RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Update**
solution 2 [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322454/syntax-for-301-redirect-of-www-to-non-www-using-httpd-conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain.com"
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com

  <Directory "/path/to/public_html">
      allow from all
      Options +Indexes
  </Directory>

  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

you can also do it with DNS setting see here [redirect non-www to www](http://www.bybe.net/blog/12-easy-steps-on-setting-up-a-non-www-to-www-redirect-using-godaddy.html)

Comment: Where exactly should I be adding this in `httpd.conf`? At the end of the file?

Comment: you can add this any where . Will better if you add this at the end.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I just removed the additional spaces. Answer updated.

Comment: Hey, it keeps my non-www url active as well. It doesnt rewrite the url to have www in it.

Comment: Sorry, its the browser that had saved the url with www. Now, if I try the non-www url, it still works. Can we make it redirect to www one?

Comment: it also can be done through DNS from your cpanel host.